# how to retrieve data from Rapid API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to retrieve list of songs from Rapid API.
Here is my script:

```
function loadData() {
      fetch("https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=eminem", {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "45ea72d0cbmsh5a68a7ddaa76fefp17c953jsn0a280e030350"
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      response.json();
    })
    .then(
     parsedJson => {
          const list = document.querySelector('.list');
      parsedJson.forEach(element => {
        const listElem = document.createElement('li')
        const textNode = document.createTextNode(element.title)
        listElem.appendChild(textNode)
        list.appendChild(listElem)
      });
     }
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    }
```

I click on button and call function loadData() but it consoles an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at D2.html:72
```

What I actually have to pass in that forEach.?

Comment: What you get when doing `console.log(parsedJson)`?

Comment: TypeError: parsedJson.forEach is not a function
    at D2.html:74

Answer (score 1):

Problem is over here

```
.then(response => {
  response.json();
})
```

you have to return response.json(); so you can resolve it

```
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
```